# Node.js yargs package on ES modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, yargs

Yargs example:

```
require('yargs')
  .scriptName("pirate-parser")
  .usage('$0 <cmd> [args]')
  .command('hello [name]', 'welcome ter yargs!', (yargs) => {
    yargs.positional('name', {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'Cambi',
      describe: 'the name to say hello to'
    })
  }, function (argv) {
    console.log('hello', argv.name, 'welcome to yargs!')
  })
  .help()
  .argv
```

how would I do this in ESM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like yargs already supports ESM: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/package.json#L10.  Have you tried changing `require('yargs')` to `import yargs from 'yargs'`?

Comment: Still gives an error:

.scriptName("pirate-parser")
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: I posted an answer which might explain better what I mean

Answer (score 7):

Yarg's [`package.json`](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/package.json#L10) points `import`s at [`./index.mjs`](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/index.mjs#L7) which exports a `YargsFactory` rather than an instance as in the `CommonJS` module.

So we need not only to `import yargs from 'yargs/yargs';`, but also to call `yargs` and pass it the `process.argv` to parse (slicing to remove the node exe and script paths).

```js
import yargs from 'yargs/yargs';

yargs(process.argv.slice(2))
  .scriptName("pirate-parser")
  .usage('$0 <cmd> [args]')
  .command('hello [name]', 'welcome ter yargs!', (yargs) => {
    yargs.positional('name', {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'Cambi',
      describe: 'the name to say hello to'
    })
  }, (argv) => {
    console.log('hello', argv.name, 'welcome to yargs!')
  })
  .help()
  .argv
```

At least that worked for me.

Comment: Correct. The old "singleton" style of using yargs is not supported with esm, the supported api is the factory.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is change `require` to `import`.

```js
import yargs from 'yargs'

yargs.scriptName("pirate-parser")
  .usage('$0 <cmd> [args]')
  .command('hello [name]', 'welcome ter yargs!', (yargs) => {
    yargs.positional('name', {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'Cambi',
      describe: 'the name to say hello to'
    })
  }, function (argv) {
    console.log('hello', argv.name, 'welcome to yargs!')
  })
  .help()
  .argv
```

Comment: This fails for me unfortunately. As per the comment above, i also see `"TypeError: yargs.scriptName is not a function"`. This is when runnning latest yargs, in node 18, with "type": "module" in my package.json .

Comment: I think it's because we're getting a `YargsFactory` rather than a yargs instance (see https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/index.mjs#L7). I needed to call `yargs()` to get it to stop failing, but it still didn't work. It doesn't seem to read the argv properly...